# Repair chipped marble countertop

Tags: countertops, marble

I would like to fix this small hole on marble countertop. It was caused by a sharp knife edge.
Goal is to make it even and smooth again but not sure what i need to do.
Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: My guess is that you will have to dremel it out so that you have a smooth mating surface, put in some color-matched epoxy, sand it down smooth, buff the marble, and seal the marble.

Comment: Watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FctBnRl3DQQ for more tips

Comment: @MonkeyZeus this is good, you should add this an answer, perhaps with a screenshot of the video

Comment: @P2000 Too little, too late for me. There are already good answers below. I was skeptical about my suggestion with the dremel so I hesitated to provide it as an answer since I've never repaired marble. Think of my comment as "Schrödinger's Answer" =D

Comment: @MonkeyZeus ha ha, you didn't know if it would work until someone tried it and so it was both a good and a bad idea until then. Brilliant, I'm going to borrow that term.

Answer (score 5):

Epoxy is the way to go, but I would not dremel it out, leave it irregular as it is. It will need to be CLEAN, no contaminates, otherwise it may require a dremel tool. Keep it irregular since the "marbling" is irregular too, it will blend in better. Over fill slightly and use a very sharp single edged razor blade to cut the excess off. You can use a clear epoxy, that will pull color from the surrounding stone. I believe clear epoxy is still a little milky in color, so that will blend in even better.

Comment: Would you apply the blade when the epoxy is fully cured or when still a bit "chewy"?

Comment: I have only seen what the pros do, and I believe they carve it while it has gotten its initial set. The blade must be a new one out of the package, NOT a used one, if it has a nick it, even a minute one will scratch the marble. When working with epoxy, I always set aside a little of the same mix to check its hardness, also so I can at least have a little test sample to try first.

Answer (score 1):

Your home store usually carries epoxy repair kits.
Note it is almost impossible to match colors I found a kit a few years back that used a putty like 2 part epoxy you mixed the putty until you got it close in color  the trick was to not end up with a solid color funny that a solid white patch the exact color shows up like a neon sign but add a gray stripe and it looks better then sand and seal, the epoxy I used took up to 8 hours to fully cure even though it set in less than 10 minutes, so I waited until the next day buffed it out cleaned and resealed the entire side.
I wish I had photos to share I got the epoxy kit at a home store called Jerry’s a competitor to Lowe’s and Home Depot in my area.
I have used other kits that were more liquid and colors but if you can find the putty one I thought it was the best and it was there recommendation to not have a solid color patch, but the 2 part or actually 3 part if you count the colors made a patch I had trouble finding after sealing the customer was ecstatic.